# AWS ECS private namespace list-instances remain unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

i have a private namespace with a service im using for ECS service discovery. The service is created like so

```
aws servicediscovery create-service --name elixir --dns-config 'NamespaceId="ns-XXXXX",DnsRecords=[{Type="A",TTL="300"}]' --health-check-custom-config FailureThreshold=1 --region XXXX --profile XXXX
```

My custom healthcheck in my task definition is:

```
 sh -c curl localhost:4000/status
```

docker ps lists each instance as healthy - ec2 status checks are 2/2/green - yet i cant seem to get the discovery service list-instances to flip from IS_INITIALIZING: true, and AWS_INIT_HEALTH_STATUS: UNHEALTHY.

The service discovery DNS properly routes to each instance as by design.

Answer (score 0):

Opened a ticket with AWS - it turns out that this is a bug on their side that is specific to the US-WEST-2 (AFAICT) region where the service discovery is not updating properly on Ec2 init and status check. I will update this when its resolved.